# Notation for the element with the maximum value

Tags: notation

I have a set of elements $A$ and a function which assigns a value $d_{a}$ to each element $a\in A$.

I am looking for a notation for the element $a$ with the lowest value $d_{a}$.

What I have found so far is the argmax function, but I am not sure if I am using it correctly or if I even need to use it:

$a_{max} = \arg\max_{a\in A}(d_{a})$

Comment: If you want the lowest value, you should use $arg\ min$ ! Otherwise I think it is correct to write it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Please notice your title contradicts the body of your question: you state in the title you need notation for the argument value giving the *maximum* value of the function, while according to the body, you need notation for the argument value giving the *minimum* value of the function.

Assuming the body is correct, then apart from that you obviously need $\arg\min$, your usage is absolutely correct.

For better typesetting, you can use the `\limits` $\LaTeX$ operator like that:
$$\arg\min\limits_{a\in A}\left(d_a\right);$$
the $\LaTeX$ source for the above is as follows: `\arg\min\limits_{a\in A}\left(d_a\right);`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a notation for the element aa with the lowest value dada.

Therefore the notation you're looking for is rather $\arg \min_{a \in A} d_a$. This notation literally means *the element $a$ of $A$ such that $d_a$ is minimum*.